# How to replace last <a> tag from section using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have section as follows

```
 <section class="breadCrumb">
     <a href="/">Home</a> <span class="divider">&gt;</span> <a class="CMSBreadCrumbsLink" href="/SCCU.Stg/Events-Calendar.aspx">Events Calendar</a> &gt; 
     <a href="/SCCU.Stg/Events-Calendar/Events-Details.aspx">Events Details</a> 

    </section>
```

it is dynamically generated by code, in the above section at some places I have  tag inside section as follows

```
 <section class="breadCrumb">
 <a href="/">Home</a> <span class="divider">&gt;</span> <a class="CMSBreadCrumbsLink" href="/SCCU.Stg/Events-Calendar.aspx">Events Calendar</a> &gt; 
 <span class="CMSBreadCrumbsCurrentItem">Events Details</span>

</section>
```

So, if you observed above both the  HTML code section, you will find one anchor tag and in another section I have span tag, so basically I want to find if Section having class name "breadCrumb" contains last  tag attribute I want to convert/replace this anchor tag with span tag and this span class as "CMSBreadCrumbsCurrentItem".
How can we do that using jquery.

In above two sections first section has  tag at last and another section don't have  tag so code would execute only for first section not for second section.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this would make it nicely:

```
$("#breadCrumb").(":last").
contents().unwrap().wrap('<span/>').addClass("CMSBreadCrumbsCurrentItem");
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it works if I have <a> tag at last in section, but Some places I have <span> instead of <a> inside section, so I want to check if last tag inside section is <a> tag then only I have to replace this <a> tag with <span> tag. So can  you suggest code for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will solve your problem** 
`$(".breadCrumb").append("<span class='CMSBreadCrumbsCurrentItem'>" + $(".breadCrumb a").last().html() +"</span>");
$(".breadCrumb a").last().html()`

Answer (score 0):

Use following script:

```
if($(".breadCrumb a").last().length){    
  $(".breadCrumb a").last().remove();
  $(".breadCrumb").append('<spanclass="CMSBreadCrumbsCurrentItem">Events Details</span>');

}
```

Comment: You have hardcoded value of <a> tag i.e. Event Details, this value is dynamic value. and one more thing I want to check if the last tag is <a> tag inside BreadCrumb section if it is <a> tag then only I have to replace anchor tag with span, but if last tag in "BreadCrumb" section is <span> then I don't want to do anything

Comment: Ya so that's way I have checked the existence of anchor tag if it is exist then adding span otherwise not

Comment: This would replace the last anchor even if that anchor was not the last tag in the section.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.breadCrum').each(function(){
  var l = $('>:last-child', this);
  if (l.prop('nodeName')=='A') {
    l.contents().unwrap().wrap('<span class="CMSBreadCrumbsCurrentItem"></span>');
  }
});
```

Edit: added > to :last, and changed :last to :last-child and changed tagName to nodeName (sorry using ipad to type my answer)

Comment: Actually tagName and nodeName do the same thing in this case. Got confused for a sec there.